# Is Cube World dead?

Tags: cube-world

do you remember CubeWorld and the hype around it... To end as said as it did. Do you know if it's still in work, if it will ever be finished? Has anyone been able to make contact with the developer?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the developer's, Wolfram von Funck, [Twitter](https://twitter.com/wol_lay) page, his [last post](https://twitter.com/wol_lay/status/722406160158994432) was on April 19. Seeing as he and his wife are the only people behind the game, I think they're just working at their own pace. Development still seems to be going on, so **No, the game is not dead.** The shop on [Picroma](https://picroma.com) has been closed for a few years, however, so there is currently no *legal* way to get the game.

Hope this helps!